# How to reload a screen in tabNavigator?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

I have 3 tabs in which whenever the user clicks on any tab i want to reload that screen. I am using `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)` retrieving index value and reloading when the index value matches with tab index. But `componentWillReceiveProps(newProps)` is fired on every tab change and reload in the background. How can i restrict it and are they any feature like `didFocus` in react navigation v1.

Thank you in advance, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Edited:

Here i am assigning the tab index in one of the tab.

tab1.js

```
componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    AsyncStorage.setItem(global.ASVtankIndex, newProps.screenProps.route_index.toString());
}
```

My tab navigator has a stack navigator in it. In one of the screen in the stack i am doing this.
screenInsideStack.js

```
 async componentWillReceiveProps(newProps) {
    var index = await AsyncStorage.getItem(global.ASVtankIndex);
    if (index === '0') {
        // reloading
    }
}
```

It works perfectly but the issue is it reloads when navigated to other screens in stack.

Comment: Do you have a code sample/live snippet that shows the problem?

Comment: Yes, i have update the question. Please check it